Latex to png of the specific portion
I am using the Overleaf online editor.
I am using the code below
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\pagestyle{empty}


 \begin{document}
 
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item The function $f(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{2}{x}$ has a local minima at $x$ equal to
\end{enumerate}

\begin{tabular}{c c}
   
    (A) 2 & \hspace{1cm} (B) 1 \\
    
    (C) 0 & \hspace{1cm} (D) -2 \\
    
\end{tabular} \\
The common region determined by all the constraints \\ 
of a linear programming problem is called:


\end{document}

getting this output

and it is okay. But I want this as png so using latexmkrc transparent background but there (in the png) is the whole page which is blank almost except the above code output then downloading the png I have to crop it, which is tedious work.
So, I just want the png of that portion only...
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advanced...
I have tried it as pagestyle{empty}, but it did not worked.

If I understand your problem correctly, than you like trim resulted document to area of your text, something like this:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}  % added
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1ex}           % added


\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item The function $f(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{2}{x}$ has a local minima at $x$ equal to
\end{enumerate}

\begin{tabular}{c c}
    (A) 2 & \hspace{1cm} (B) 1 \\
    (C) 0 & \hspace{1cm} (D) -2 \\
\end{tabular} \\
The common region determined by all the constraints \\
of a linear programming problem is called:
\end{preview}
\end{document}

where is employed preview packe, or something like this:

\documentclass[margin=2mm, varwidth]{standalone}  % <---
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item The function $f(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{2}{x}$ has a local minima at $x$ equal to
\end{enumerate}

\begin{tabular}{c c}
    (A) 2 & \hspace{1cm} (B) 1 \\
    (C) 0 & \hspace{1cm} (D) -2 \\
\end{tabular} \\
The common region determined by all the constraints \\
of a linear programming problem is called:
\end{document}

where is employed standalone packe.
